# Implementing a MongoDB Logger in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, logging

I'm on Rails 3.2.11

I'd like to put my application's log entries into a MongoDB collection, as I have a multi-tenant app and would like to filter the entries by account, time ranges, tags, etc.

What's the simplest way to implement something like this?  I figure I'd use Moped or Mongoid to save the data.

EDIT:

[mbasset's](https://github.com/mbasset/central_logger) version of central_logger works with the latest Rails, and just required a few tweeks to get working with my own system.  Will write those down at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly nice implementation [here on GitHub](https://github.com/customink/central_logger) which is currently failing. Probably due to a lack of maintenance with the last few minor Rails updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http://mongodb-logger.catware.org It support Rails 3+ and Rack apps.